# ignore file extension with Jest

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using webpack resolve.extensions to "selectively" bundle my js files.
eg.

App.js

```
import MyComp from 'comp/myComp';
```

in `comp/` folder I have:

```
MyComp.web.js
MyComp.ios.js
MyComp.android.js
```

Now I want to write test for `App.js`, to test how it render as web. But the problem is Jest keep resolving all 3 `.js` files and that causes dependency error because I'm not running the command in a mobile environment and most mobile modules will not work.

how can I tell jest to only resolve `.js` and `.web.js` files just like webpack?

I added this to my package.json and it keep resolving `.ios.js` and `.android.js`

```
"moduleFileExtensions": ["web.js", "js", "jsx"],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "main"]
```

I tried as suggested with:

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "^.+\\.(android|ios)\\.js$"],
```

looks no effects :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `testPathIgnorePatterns` to your `package.json` file.  The value is an array of regex patterns.  Any file/path that matches an expression will be ignored/skipped from testing.

See [these Jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#testpathignorepatterns-array-string) for more detail

Comment: I did try ``"testPathIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "^.+\\.(ios|android)\\.js$"],`` but still not working as expected :S

Comment: I'm not sure your pattern needs to be so fine-tuned. Can you try again with simply ["MyComp.android.js", "MyComp.ios.js"] and let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried with full absolute path, but it still showing error stack from MyComp.ios.js...  I think the problem is more like to tell Jest if there is no extension at the import, resolve with `.web.js` extension and then `.js`

Comment: Interesting.  Okay - two questions: 1. What is the command you are using to run your tests? Are you running them through `npm`?  2: Do you have any other Jest configs in your `package.json` file?  Maybe even post the contents of that file.

Comment: I found the reason... it has the preset of `jest-react-native` inside of jest, I replaced it to `"preset": "react-native"` and it worked. Now I externalized into several jest config file and works great, thanks

Comment: Awesome - happy that you were able to get it resolved :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can also remap files to an empty file

```
touch empty.js
```

In your jest config add following

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|jpg|png|scss|less|sass)$': '<rootDir>/empty.js',
  },
```

Works perfect for me